# Imageviews in vertical Scrollview loaded with Picasso are not shown/refrshed

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview, picasso, android-lazyloading

In Android, we need to fill a vertical `scrollview` dynamically with different kind of contents, like text, titles, and images.

Every content type is managed by a `Fragment`, which is dynamically inflated in the root `fragment` which represents the view.

For background image loading we are currently using `Picasso`.
Everything works perfectly in the article page, but the images are non refreshed/shown, apart from the first one which is immediately visible on top of the `scrollview`.

So, for example, if we have one image on top of the `scrollview`, it is immediately loaded and shown. 
When we scroll down, even if `Picasso` has downloaded the following images, they are not shown in the layout.
But once we go back on the backstack and reopen again that view, all the images are shown, meaning that `Picasso` had correctly stored the image in the cache.

How can we force `Picasso` (or the `Scrollview`) to refresh the layout of the contained images even if they are not visible at that moment in the `scrollview`? Is it possible to implement lazy-loading of the images in the `Scrollview`? How?

Comment: Without any code it would be very hard for us to look at your problem. However I can suggest using a RecyclerView instead of a ScrollView. You can use it with a [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) to achieve the layout you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Benito, we've converted the Scrollview into a RecyclerView as per your suggestion and now it works perfectly. Strange enough, the images loaded with Picasso in background into a Scrollview don't get refreshed. Thanks again